# 2D Runner Highscore Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey Guys I'm having some Problems with my Highscore in a Unity game. Its a 2d runner in which I save the Player Distance in a Variable and want to check when the Player is dead if distance is higher than Highscore. But I have a Error and can't figure out what the problem is. Can somebody help me, I'm pretty new to c#.

Heres my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class UIController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Player player;
    Text distanceText;

    GameObject results;
    Text finalDistanceText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Player>();
        distanceText = GameObject.Find("DistanceText").GetComponent<Text>();
        results = GameObject.Find("Results");
        finalDistanceText = GameObject.Find("FinalDistanceText").GetComponent<Text>();
        HighscoreNumber = GameObject.Find("HighscoreNumber").GetComponent<Text>();
        results.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int distance = Mathf.FloorToInt(player.distance);
        distanceText.text = distance + " m";
        


        if (player.isDead)
        {
            results.SetActive(true);
            finalDistanceText.text = distance + " m";
            if (distance > Highscore)
            {
                int Highscore = distance
                HighscoreNumber.text = Highscore + " m";
            }
        }
    }


    public void Quit()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    }

    public void Retry()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");
    }

    
}
```

Comment: It would help if you showed what the error says, but basically you have an `int Highscore` variable that you declare inside an `if` statement that you use in the `if` statement. That doesn't make a lot of sense, the scope of your `int Highscore` variable is limited to the inside of the `if` i.e. nothing outside of the `if` can see that variable because it's declared inside it. Put the `Highscore` variable in class scope instead of local scope.

Comment: Oh yeah I understand what you mean, but I'm not sure with what I should Highscore declerade when I can't put it in a if statement. @Charleh

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#`

Comment: This code won't even compile. Try posting what you're really using.

Answer (score 0):

In your  second if statment inside update method you use `HighScore` in comparison then declare variable with the same name on the next line.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: try change the if statement to this  ```if (distance > int.Parse(HighscoreNumber.text.Remove(HighscoreNumber.text.length-1,1)))```

Comment: No - parsing like this is a bad idea - you already know the current score and the high score, why would you start parsing text from a textbox? Parsing is for taking input or data and making sense of it - the OP already has the two bits of data they need, why would you parse anything?!

Comment: from the above code you don't have the HighScore stored as a number only CurrentScore. you only have it as string with 'm' suffix. if you don't want to parse it you can store  on the Awake method by parsing the ```HighscoreNumber .text``` using the same parse as above

Answer (score 0):

Couple issues that I can see.  You'll be getting an error for `HighscoreNumber` being assigned to before being declared.

```
class UIController : MonoBehaviour {
Text highScore
//...

    void Awake() {
        highScore = GameObject.Find...
    }
}
```

The next issue is that you're declaring a `Highscore` locally after you try to use it in the if statement:

```
// Highscore doesn't exist yet so you can't compare distance against it.
if (distance > Highscore)
{
    // The int here means you're making a new variable that only lives inside the braces and setting it to distance.
    int Highscore = distance
    HighscoreNumber.text = Highscore + " m";
}
```

If this UIComponent stays alive between scene loads, you could just move the declaration to the class level.

```
public class UIController : MonoBehavior {
    int highScore = 0  //I get set to 0 when the UIController component is created.
    //...

    void Update() {
      //...
        // Since highScore is declared at the scope of the class, the if statement and assignment inside both have access.
        if(distance > highScore) {
            highScore = distance;
        }
    }
}
```

The other issue is that it looks like the UIComponent may be getting disposed and re-created when you restart the scene so will likely be reset to 0 between restarts.  You'll want to look at something like the Singleton method described here:
https://www.sitepoint.com/saving-data-between-scenes-in-unity/

This is just what came up when I Googled, there's probably a bunch of examples but that should help you know what to search.

However, this will only survive as long as the game is running.  If you want to retain the high score between game launches, you'll want to look at something like this:
https://blog.unity.com/technology/persistent-data-how-to-save-your-game-states-and-settings